# How can i prevent prettier from addin </body>

Tags: ejs, prettier

I want to save an ejs file with a `<body>`.

prettier keeps adding `</body>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to the list of ignored elements in the Prettier config file. Create a **.prettierignore**  file in the root directory and add `**/</body>` to it.